# Grouping multiple datetime dataframe rows into a single one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with some date time interval. I am trying to squash them into single events.
I have the start and end time alongside the respective duration for every event.

What I have

```
           start_time            end_time  duration  id
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 00:30:00        30   A
1 2020-01-01 00:30:00 2020-01-01 01:00:00        30   B
2 2020-01-01 01:00:00 2020-01-01 01:30:00        30   C
3 2020-01-01 01:30:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00        30   D
4 2020-01-04 05:00:00 2020-01-04 05:30:00        30   E
5 2020-01-04 05:30:00 2020-01-04 06:00:00        30   F
6 2020-01-04 06:00:00 2020-01-04 06:30:00        30   G
7 2020-01-04 06:30:00 2020-01-04 07:00:00        30   H
8 2020-01-04 20:30:00 2020-01-04 21:00:00        30   I
```

What I'm trying to squash it into

```
           start_time            end_time  duration  id
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00       120   A
4 2020-01-04 05:00:00 2020-01-04 07:00:00       120   E
8 2020-01-04 20:30:00 2020-01-04 21:00:00        30   I
```

I looked for group and merging options in pandas but I didn't manage to to what I want.

Comment: Are your intervals such that an overlap is only ever possible at the cutpoints? If so a simple `shift` gets you the grouping. But if more complicated overlaps are possible then the logic gets more complicated.

Comment: They don't overlapped they always follow each other. I'm going to look into shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)

```
 new_df =( df.groupby(df['end_time'].dt.date,as_index = False)
             .agg({'start_time':'first',
                    'end_time':'last',
                    'duration':'sum',
                    'id':'first'})
         )
print(new_df)

           start_time            end_time  duration id
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00       120  A
1 2020-01-04 05:00:00 2020-01-04 07:00:00       120  E
```

Comment: To be perfect, I just changed the end_time aggregation function to be 'last' instead of 'first'. Thank you very much sir :)

Comment: I am glad to help:) , please consider accept the answer

Comment: I just realise that if you have another row of data that is the same day but very late it got combined with the other one (off the same day).
I've updated the initial post

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to compare end times with the shifted start times and set any identical pairs to null:

```
df['flag'] = df['start_time'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df['end_time'] == df['flag'], 'flag'] = pd.NaT
print(df)                                                              
           start_time            end_time  duration id                flag
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 00:30:00        30  A                 NaT
1 2020-01-01 00:30:00 2020-01-01 01:00:00        30  B                 NaT
2 2020-01-01 01:00:00 2020-01-01 01:30:00        30  C                 NaT
3 2020-01-01 01:30:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00        30  D 2020-01-04 05:00:00
4 2020-01-04 05:00:00 2020-01-04 05:30:00        30  E                 NaT
5 2020-01-04 05:30:00 2020-01-04 06:00:00        30  F                 NaT
6 2020-01-04 06:00:00 2020-01-04 06:30:00        30  G                 NaT
7 2020-01-04 06:30:00 2020-01-04 07:00:00        30  H 2020-01-04 20:30:00
8 2020-01-04 20:30:00 2020-01-04 21:00:00        30  I                 NaT
```

Then use [`DataFrame.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) to backfill those nulls with the start time that violate your interval condition. You'll need to manually set the null value yourself for the last value.

```
df['flag'] = df['flag'].bfill().fillna(df['end_time'].iloc[-2])
print(df)                                                         
           start_time            end_time  duration id                flag
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 00:30:00        30  A 2020-01-04 05:00:00
1 2020-01-01 00:30:00 2020-01-01 01:00:00        30  B 2020-01-04 05:00:00
2 2020-01-01 01:00:00 2020-01-01 01:30:00        30  C 2020-01-04 05:00:00
3 2020-01-01 01:30:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00        30  D 2020-01-04 05:00:00
4 2020-01-04 05:00:00 2020-01-04 05:30:00        30  E 2020-01-04 20:30:00
5 2020-01-04 05:30:00 2020-01-04 06:00:00        30  F 2020-01-04 20:30:00
6 2020-01-04 06:00:00 2020-01-04 06:30:00        30  G 2020-01-04 20:30:00
7 2020-01-04 06:30:00 2020-01-04 07:00:00        30  H 2020-01-04 20:30:00
8 2020-01-04 20:30:00 2020-01-04 21:00:00        30  I 2020-01-04 07:00:00
```

Now do as [ansev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59900869/12777044) suggested:

```
df = df.groupby('flag').agg({'start_time':'first','end_time':'last','duration':'sum','id':'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)                                                                         
           start_time            end_time  duration id
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 02:00:00       120  A
1 2020-01-04 20:30:00 2020-01-04 21:00:00        30  I
2 2020-01-04 05:00:00 2020-01-04 07:00:00       120  E
```